# Why there is no `latest` version label in maven repositories like mvnrepository.com or nexus?

Tags: maven, artifactory, nexus

Why `mvnrepository.com` or `nexus` does not follow a convention to have a `latest` version, for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>latest</version>
</dependency>
```

The version `latest` will always point to the latest version in the repository so instead of updating the `pom.xml` file, during the build, it will pick the latest on. Provided the library is backward compatible.

Comment: It is difficult to answer 'why' type of questions. I believe that non-reproducible builds are to be avoided, and the feature you propose is harmful in the long run (example: I've been bitten by inconsistent builds and non-backward compatible updates in docker, that provides such feature). I guess maven maintainers share my point of view.

Comment: First `latest` will not work cause it is not defined that way. Furthermore as already mentioned reproducibility is the key point. Apart from that you don't know if a library will follow any kind of convention like semver etc but it does not change anything cause if you would use `latest` this could replace a version `1.2.3` with `2.1.0` which could break your whole code. Apart from all before there is no such convention using `latest` it's the same as using version ranges which should be avoided. You will get a warning if you use such things for a good reason.

Comment: BTW: mvnrepository is no maven repository it's search engine...